# How to return previous row's value when current row's value is null in a monthly sequence of rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

Thank you for any help you may provide.

In MS Access

I want to return the last dividend that occurred in every row.  Each row is keyed to Ticker and Month.   Every 3 months there is a dividend.   I want to return the most recent dividend even when the current row value is null.

Here's what I have attempted, but there is an unspecified syntax error in the FROM clauses.   The result table would be identical to the source, but with the previous Dividend value in every row wherever it is null.

```
SELECT
  t1.Ticker,
  t1.[Market Price],
  t1.Dividend AS VEDiv,
  t1.[VE Rating] AS VERating,
  t1.Momentum,
  t1.[Momentum Ranking],
  t1.[One Year Target],
  t1.[One Year Forecast],
  t1.[Market Cap],
  t1.Ticker & t1.[Month] AS joinder,
  IIF(t1.Dividend IS NOT NULL, t1.Dividend, 0) AS Dividend
FROM MonthlyData_USA_202306 AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t2.Ticker, t2.[Month], MAX(t2.[Month]) AS PrevMonth
  FROM MonthlyData_USA_202306 AS t2
  WHERE t2.Dividend IS NOT NULL
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM MonthlyData_USA_202306 AS t3
      WHERE t3.Ticker = t2.Ticker
     AND t3.[Month] < t2.[Month]
     )
  GROUP BY 
     t2.Ticker, t2.[Month] )  AS t3 
ON (t1.Ticker = t3.Ticker) AND (t1.[Month] = t3.[Month]) 
LEFT JOIN MonthlyData_USA_202306 AS t4
  ON (t3.Ticker = t4.Ticker) AND ( t3.PrevMonth = t4.[Month] )
ORDER BY t1.Ticker, t1.[Month];
```

This is the original data:

| ID | Ticker | Month | Market Price | VE Rating | One Month Forecast | Momentum | Momentum Ranking | Market Cap | One Year Target | One Year Forecast | Dividend | DDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | AA | 20220531 | 61.72 | 3 | 0.0060563087 | 0.5558357 | 94 | 11384.192 | 64.10159 | 0.038587037 | 0.1 |  |
| 3 | AA | 20220630 | 45.58 | 3 | 0.0052011013 | 0.23724218 | 91 | 8200.982 | 46.87313 | 0.028370548 |  |  |
| 4 | AA | 20220729 | 50.89 | 2 | -0.0034490228 | 0.26749682 | 89 | 9156.383 | 46.68581 | -0.08261331 |  |  |
| 5 | AA | 20220831 | 49.48 | 2 | -0.00016868114 | 0.11516792 | 83 | 8902.689 | 46.81598 | -0.053840324 | 0.1 |  |
| 6 | AA | 20220930 | 33.66 | 3 | 0.0029562712 | -0.31221902 | 35 | 5955.699 | 34.59156 | 0.027675677 |  |  |
| 7 | AA | 20221031 | 39.03 | 2 | -0.005019963 | -0.15059851 | 55 | 6905.8506 | 34.993958 | -0.103408664 | 0.1 |  |
| 8 | AA | 20221130 | 50.13 | 1 | -0.0067557693 | 0.07736949 | 73 | 8869.852 | 43.439503 | -0.13346298 |  |  |
| 9 | AA | 20221230 | 45.47 | 2 | 0.0018171072 | -0.23682444 | 40 | 8045.3257 | 41.49046 | -0.08752009 |  |  |
| 10 | AA | 20230131 | 52.24 | 2 | -0.0027022362 | -0.07882203 | 48 | 9243.189 | 47.091152 | -0.09856144 |  |  |
| 11 | AA | 20230228 | 48.94 | 3 | 0.003370285 | -0.35041144 | 14 | 8659.296 | 47.598236 | -0.02741647 |  |  |
| 12 | AA | 20230331 | 42.56 | 3 | 0.0045433044 | -0.52726865 | 6 | 7592.747 | 42.999767 | 0.010332774 | 0.12 |  |
| 13 | AA | 20230428 | 37.14 | 3 | 0.004954338 | -0.45221242 | 6 | 6625.813 | 38.487164 | 0.03627265 |  |  |
| 14 | AA | 20230531 | 31.72 | 4 | 0.0060737133 | -0.48606613 | 6 | 5658.8794 | 33.305996 | 0.05 |  |  |

I want it to be thus:

| ID | Ticker | Month | Market Price | VE Rating | One Month Forecast | Momentum | Momentum Ranking | Market Cap | One Year Target | One Year Forecast | Dividend | DDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | AA | 20220531 | 61.72 | 3 | 0.0060563087 | 0.5558357 | 94 | 11384.192 | 64.10159 | 0.038587037 | 0.1 |  |
| 3 | AA | 20220630 | 45.58 | 3 | 0.0052011013 | 0.23724218 | 91 | 8200.982 | 46.87313 | 0.028370548 | 0.1 |  |
| 4 | AA | 20220729 | 50.89 | 2 | -0.0034490228 | 0.26749682 | 89 | 9156.383 | 46.68581 | -0.08261331 | 0.1 |  |
| 5 | AA | 20220831 | 49.48 | 2 | -0.00016868114 | 0.11516792 | 83 | 8902.689 | 46.81598 | -0.053840324 | 0.1 |  |
| 6 | AA | 20220930 | 33.66 | 3 | 0.0029562712 | -0.31221902 | 35 | 5955.699 | 34.59156 | 0.027675677 | 0.1 |  |
| 7 | AA | 20221031 | 39.03 | 2 | -0.005019963 | -0.15059851 | 55 | 6905.8506 | 34.993958 | -0.103408664 | 0.1 |  |
| 8 | AA | 20221130 | 50.13 | 1 | -0.0067557693 | 0.07736949 | 73 | 8869.852 | 43.439503 | -0.13346298 | 0.1 |  |
| 9 | AA | 20221230 | 45.47 | 2 | 0.0018171072 | -0.23682444 | 40 | 8045.3257 | 41.49046 | -0.08752009 | 0.1 |  |
| 10 | AA | 20230131 | 52.24 | 2 | -0.0027022362 | -0.07882203 | 48 | 9243.189 | 47.091152 | -0.09856144 | 0.1 |  |
| 11 | AA | 20230228 | 48.94 | 3 | 0.003370285 | -0.35041144 | 14 | 8659.296 | 47.598236 | -0.02741647 | 0.1 |  |
| 12 | AA | 20230331 | 42.56 | 3 | 0.0045433044 | -0.52726865 | 6 | 7592.747 | 42.999767 | 0.010332774 | 0.12 |  |
| 13 | AA | 20230428 | 37.14 | 3 | 0.004954338 | -0.45221242 | 6 | 6625.813 | 38.487164 | 0.03627265 | 0.12 |  |
| 14 | AA | 20230531 | 31.72 | 4 | 0.0060737133 | -0.48606613 | 6 | 5658.8794 | 33.305996 | 0.05 | 0.12 |  |

Please note how in 20230331 the dividend increases and that value is expressed in 20230428 and 20230531 as well.

Here is the result of the "join by quarters query."  As you can see, the rows are not unique.

| ID | Ticker | Month | Market Price | VE Rating | One Month Forecast | Momentum | Momentum Ranking | Market Cap | One Year Target | One Year Forecast | Dividend | Qtr | Div |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.1 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.1 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.12 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.1 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.1 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.132 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.18 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.194 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.21 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.1 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 6.8 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 6.8 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.35 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.75 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.875 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.875 |
| 1 | AA | 20220429 | 67.8 | 4 | 0.009176612 | 0.8504368 | 96 | 12505.644 | 71.71813 | 0.057789594 |  | 2 | 0.875 |

Answer (score 2):

Pulling data from another record of same table is not simple in Access.

Can use TOP 1 in correlated subquery, however, performance may be slow.

```
SELECT MonthlyData_USA_202306.*, 
Nz(MonthlyData_USA_202306.Dividend, (
    SELECT TOP 1 Dividend FROM MonthlyData_USA_202306 AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.Month<MonthlyData_USA_202306.Month AND NOT Dupe.Dividend IS NULL 
    ORDER BY Dupe.Month DESC)) AS Div
FROM MonthlyData_USA_202306;
```

Include `Dupe.Ticker = MonthlyData_USA_202306.Ticker` in WHERE clause if must consider multiple tickers.

Comment: Thank you very much June.   This is, IMHO, a briliant approach, the elements of which, I was unaware.   I don't know enough to fix the error generated by the top query, though.  The top query produces the following error:  "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."  That is what we want the subquery to do, yes?

Comment: I don't know why you get error. These queries are exactly what I used with your sample data. I don't understand requirement in your second comment. Edit your question to state this requirement and show desired result as a table or start a new question.

Comment: Thank you June, for helping me explain myself and my requirement better.   I have edited the original question per your suggestion.     In the original data, there is a dividend every 3rd row.    I want the query to return dividends in every row such that if there is no dividend in the original data, the query fills in data from the most recent row before the empty-dividend row.   I hope that helps.  Please see my question for the examples you requested.

Comment: Well, that's what I think my suggested queries accomplish.

Comment: Hi June, I do not know why I get error from your first answer query.   The error is "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."   The "SELECT TOP 1 Dividend.... sub query.   It seems to me that returning one row in the subquery is exactly what is required.   Perhaps, the error directs us to the inverse, which is to say, perhaps MS Access "thinks" it may return more than 1 row?

Comment: I'm sure you do think that is what your queries accomplish, but unfortunately, the "join on quarters query" returns non-unique rows.    I'll post the return set in my original question again.

Comment: Queries produce the desired output using posted sample data. I start with 13 records and output 13 records. So what's different about actual data? However, I discovered problem with dataset crossing years for the quarters approach.

Comment: Thank you June.   I very much appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Everyone, here is a working answer.   June, thank you again:

This query returns unique rows and returns Dividend from the most recent non-null Dividend row whenever the current row Dividend is null.:

```
SELECT Orig.*, IIf(Orig.Dividend Is Null,(SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.Dividend
      FROM MonthlyData_AllRows AS Dupe
         WHERE Dupe.Ticker = Orig.Ticker
         AND Dupe.DDate <= Orig.DDate
         AND Dupe.Dividend IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY Dupe.DDate DESC),Orig.Dividend) AS [D], (4*[D])/[Market Price] 
      AS DYld
FROM MonthlyData_AllRows AS Orig;
```